# What did Euler do with multiple zeta values?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, analytic-number-theory

When reading about multiple zeta values, I often find the claim that the case of length two 
$$
\zeta(s_1, s_2)=\sum_{n>m \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{s_1}m^{s_2}}, \qquad s_1 \geq 2, \quad s_2 \geq 1
$$
was first considered by Euler. Does anybody know what precisely he proved about these numbers?

Comment: This may fit better at http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: He was trying to understand $\zeta(3)$ after he discovered the rationality of $\zeta(2k)/\pi^{2k}$. He was unsuccessful with $\zeta(3)$ but was led to many identities among MZV (which arise naturally), the simplest being $\zeta(3) = \zeta(2,1)$. See the introduction (pages 11-13) of Bombieri's article *The classical theory of zeta and $L$-functions* in the Milan Journal of Mathematics.

Answer (score 20):

Euler proved in 1775 in [Meditationes circa singulare serierum genus](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E477.html) ("*Meditations about a singular type of series*") that
$$\sum_{i+j=n,\,i\geq 2,\;j\geq 1}\zeta(i,j)=\zeta(n),$$
as a special case of a more general [sum rule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function#The_sum_and_duality_conjectures.5B4.5D)

Notice that Euler's definition of the multiple-zeta-value is slightly different than in the OP ($n\geq m$ instead of $n>m$)

[image]